# Recommendations for books on boundary layer Meteorology?

Tags: meteorology, reference-request, planetary-boundary-layer

Does anybody have any recommendations on books tackling Boundary layer Meteorology? I've seen the book by Roland Stull and Arya, but are there any other more updated ones that are as good as these two?

Also, would anyone have a resource for the full solutions to Stull's book for BL Meteorology?

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Plenty of books available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any particular aspect of boundary layer meteorology? Or just something general?

**NOTE**: I have **not** read all of these nor do I know anyone who has read these, but judging by the year published or level of detail, these may serve whatever purpose you want. I found these mostly by Googling. I recommend looking at the preview offered in each website.

- [Turbulence by John Wyngaard- published in 2010](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01DM26POW)
- [Fundamentals of Boundary-Layer Meteorology](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Fundamentals_of_Boundary_Layer_Meteorolo/u9IxDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0&kptab=overview) by Xuhui Lee was published in 2017, but from the brief look inside, I don't see a large difference from Stull or Arya.
- [Atmospheric Boundary Layer Integrating Air Chemistry and Land Interactions (2015)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Atmospheric_Boundary_Layer/QKVwCQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)
- [Turbulence and Dispersion in the Planetary Boundary Layer By Francesco Tampieri · 2016](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Turbulence_and_Dispersion_in_the_Planeta/_pUoDQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)